# How can I find out if a web service returns data in XML or JSON format?

Tags: xml, json, web-services

If its a third party web service, how will I know if it returns data in XML or JSON format?
I guess if its created in .NET, then I just look at the WSDL provided for the web service?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always look at the HTTP headers in the response, in particular the content type. There's no guarantee they are correct, but the presence of "application/json" or "application/xml" should give you a clue.

However, knowing that the response is XML or JSON isn't going to help you much. If you don't know what the web service returns, and it returns `<akhegc snt="jsg"/>`, then knowing this is XML doesn't actually help you make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

If it has a wsdl and it adheres to the standard ( http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl ) it will emit XML.

Comment: And how would I know if it is JSON?

Comment: as a rule of thumb: if it has a wsdl it will be xml. Otherwise you have to test it.